# Form onClick running when Form required haven't been meet

Tags: javascript, forms, post, onclick, required

Hey guys didn't really know how to word it, But even tho I've added `required` to my form input its runs the JavaScript onsubmit even failing the `required` when the buttons pressed and the forms blank.

Is there a line i can add to my JavaScript to stop it from running when the button is pressed and the form is blank? any help would be great :D

```
<div id="div3">
    <div id="form"> 
        <form action="results.php" method="post" >
        <input type="text" id="field" name="field" required>
        <input id="submit" name="submit"  type="image" src="gif/button.png"  onClick="test();" value="submit"></form>       
    </div><div id="msg"><b>
<span id="msgtxt">Hello</span>
<span id="img"><img src="gif/loadingdot.gif"></span></b>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascrpt

```
function test()
{
    $('#msg').attr('style','display:block;');
    $('#msgtxt').html('Connecting To Server');

    setTimeout(function(){  //Beginning of code that should run AFTER the timeout
    $('#msgtxt').html('Message one');
        //lots more code
    },5000);  // put the timeout here
    setTimeout(function(){  //Beginning of code that should run AFTER the timeout
    $('#msgtxt').html('Message two);
        //lots more code
    },7000);  // put the timeout here
    setTimeout(function(){  //Beginning of code that should run AFTER the timeout
    $('#msgtxt').html('Message three');
        //lots more code
    },11000);  // put the timeout here
    setTimeout(function(){
        txt=$("#field").val();
        $.post("results.php",{field:txt},function(result){
            $("#div3").html(result);
        });
        $('#msg').attr('style','display:none;');
    },17000);
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post("form.html",{field:'mytext'},function(result){
            $("#load").html(result);
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it :

```
<input id="submit" name="submit"  type="image" src="gif/button.png"  onClick="check();" value="submit">
```

and then the check(); function :

```
var check = function(){
    if ($("#field").val() != "" )
        test();
    else
        $('#msgtxt').html('form is empty');
}
```